# angular-mock testing in Karma+Mocha can't find module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm learning AJS unit testing, with RequireJS, Karma, Mocha, Chai and angular-mocks. I've had some luck with the first four, but need to get into "real" testing and can't get angular-mocks to work. There's a lot going on, so I'll be as succinct as possible.

**test/karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        // requirejs may need to be listed before other modules (see https://github.com/princed/karma-chai-plugins#limited-requirejs-support)
        frameworks: ["requirejs", "mocha", "chai"],

        files: [
            // load the RequireJS config files first
            {pattern: "client/app/require-shared.js",                                     watched: false},
            {pattern: "test/require-test.js",                                             watched: false},

            // set included to false for files to be loaded via RequireJS
            {pattern: "client/**/*.js",                                  included: false                },
            {pattern: "bower_components/**/*.js",                        included: false, watched: false},

            // Mocha stuff
            {pattern: "test/unit/mocha.conf.js",                                          watched: false},

            // test files
            {pattern: "test/unit/**/pageSelectorTest.js",                           included: false                }
        ],
        exclude: [
            "client/app/bootstrap.js",
            "client/app/require-main.js",
            "*.conf.js"
        ],

        reporters: ["spec"],

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,

        browsers: [
            "PhantomJS"
        ],

        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

**test/unit/mocha.conf.js**

```
window.mocha.setup({
    ui: "tdd"
});
```

**test/unit/MyTest.js**

```
define([
     "angular-mocks"
    ,"app"
], function () {
    "use strict";

    var MODULE_NAME = "PageSelector";
    var assert = chai.assert;


    suite("Unit testing " + MODULE_NAME, function() {
        suite(MODULE_NAME + " module", function () {
            var appModule;

            setup(function () {
                // "ng" and "ngMock" modules automatically loaded
                appModule = angular.mock.module(MODULE_NAME);
                console.log(appModule);
            });

//          setup(function () {
//              angular.mock.inject(function () {
//
//              });
//          });

            test("should exist", function () {
                assert.isDefined(appModule, "module exists");
            });
        }); // end module tests
    });
});
```

I'll skip posting all the RequireJS config. I'm pretty sure I'm getting `angular` and `angular-mocks`, because I've worked through those errors already.

My Gruntfile simply has an option to load `karma.conf.js`. The output of `grunt karma` is:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)]: Connected on socket WJUF8xogEo-XCG-8zzJX with id 10483911
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)
LOG LOG: undefined

  Unit testing PageSelector
    PageSelector module
      ✗ should exist
        AssertionError: module exists: expected undefined to not equal undefined
            at /home/client/node_modules/chai/chai.js:925
            at assertEqual (/home/client/node_modules/chai/chai.js:1402)
            at /home/client/node_modules/chai/chai.js:3627
            at /home/client/node_modules/chai/chai.js:2648
            at /home/client/test/unit/utility/pageSelectorTest.js:37
            at callFn (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4338)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4728
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4819
            at next (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4653)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4663
            at next (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4601)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4625
            at done (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4300)
            at callFn (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4343)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
            at next (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4626)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4625
            at done (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4300)
            at callFn (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4343)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4331
            at next (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4626)
            at /home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:4630
            at timeslice (/home/client/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:5763)


PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.003 secs / 0.002 secs)

Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

If I change `angular.mock.module(MODULE_NAME);` to `angular.module(MODULE_NAME);`, the `assert` works. What am I missing? (I apologize if there isn't enough info above. I can post more, as needed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug into angular-mocks.js. `module` is just a set-up for `inject`. On its own, it doesn't actually load a module, like `angular.module` does. I was using it unnecessarily for "module-level" testing, where `angular.module` is appropriate.

When getting in to actual controller/directive/etc. testing, I'll need the `module`+`inject` pair.

Comment: Can you please add some more information? I am facing the same issue

Comment: (angular.mocks.)module just initializes things for inject, so nothing is loaded. To actually load your module when you aren't going to follow module with inject, you have to use angular.module.