# ReferenceError: module is not defined - Karma/Jasmine configuration with Angular/Laravel app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an existing Angular/Laravel app in which Laravel acts as an API to the angular frontend serving only JSON data.  The page that loads the angular app, `index.php`, is currently served by Laravel. From there, Angular takes over.

I'm have a very difficult time trying to get started with Karma/Jasmine.  When running my tests using `karma start` or `karma start karma.conf.js` from the root directory of my project, I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Full output:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/raph/coding/webroot/digitalocean/rugapp/public/rugapp/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5)]: Connected on socket 3OCUMp_xhrGtlGHwiosO with id 7897120
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) hello world encountered a declaration exception FAILED
    ReferenceError: module is not defined
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/raph/coding/webroot/digitalocean/rugapp/tests/js/test.js:3:16)
        at jasmineInterface.describe (/Users/raph/coding/webroot/digitalocean/rugapp/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:59:18)
        at /Users/raph/coding/webroot/digitalocean/rugapp/tests/js/test.js:1:1
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Mac OS X 10.9.5): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.005 secs / 0.003 secs)
```

However, the chrome broswer does launch with the following displayed:

[image]

My `karma.conf.js` file is as follows:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Dec 22 2014 18:13:09 GMT-0500 (EST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: 'public/rugapp/',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '*.html',
      '**/*.js',
      '../../tests/js/test.js',
      '../../tests/js/angular/angular-mocks.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

My `package.json` file is shown below:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "karma": "^0.12.28",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.2",
    "laravel-elixir": "*"
  }
}
```

`test.js`

```
describe("hello world", function() {
    var CreateInvoiceController;
    beforeEach(module("MobileAngularUiExamples"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        CreateInvoiceController = $controller("CreateInvoiceController");
    }));

    describe("CreateInvoiceController", function() {
        it("Should say hello", function() {
            expect(CreateInvoiceController.message).toBe("Hello");
        });
    });
});

describe("true", function() {
    it("Should be true", function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: This maybe will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021914/angular-mock-testing-in-karmamocha-cant-find-module

Comment: Right as you posted this, I realized that my angular-mocks.js was being defined after my tests.  I finally got to the point where I have no errors, but I haven't yet injected my app's controllers.  Exciting times.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Perhaps this will help someone.

The solution, for me, was to make sure `angular-mocks.js` was loaded before my tests.  If you're not sure, you control the order in `karma.conf.js` under the following section:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
// include files / patterns here
```

Next, to get my test to actually load my angular app, I had to do the following:

```
describe("hello world", function() {
    var $rootScope;
    var $controller;
    beforeEach(module("YourAppNameHere"));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        YourControllerHere = $controller("YourControllerHere");

    }));

    it("Should say hello", function() {
        expect(YourControllerHere.message).toBe("Hello");
    });

});
```

And in your controller,

```
app.controller('YourControllerHere', function() {

    this.message = "Hello";

});
```

Also, another way:

```
describe("YourControllerHere", function() {
    var $scope;
    var controller;

    beforeEach(function() {

        module("YourAppNameHere");

        inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {

            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            controller = $controller("YourControllerHere", {$scope: $scope});

        });

    });

    it("Should say hello", function() {
        expect(controller.message).toBe("Hello");
    });

});
```

Enjoy testing!

Comment: my problem was that I didn't include angular-moch at all!

Answer (score 6):

The error means angular was not able to inject your module. Most of the time this happens because of missing reference to script files. In this case, make sure to have all your script file is defined under [files] configuration of karma. Pay special attention to paths because if your script folder has nested structure, make sure to list as such. For example:

```
Scripts/Controllers/One/1.js 
Scripts/Controllers/One/2.js
```

can be listed as in karma.conf.js>files as :

```
Scripts/Controllers/**/*.js
```

Answer (score 4):

Just leave this here for future searchers.

If you are running angular unit tests in the browser directly without Karma (or in plunkr or jsfiddle ect...) Then it may be that

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0/angular-cookies.js"></script> 

    <!-- The Mocha Setup goes BETWEEN angular and angular-mocks -->
    <script>
      mocha.setup({
        "ui": "bdd",
        "reporter": "html"
      });
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="myTest.js"></script> <!-- test is last -->
```

The Mocha Setup goes BETWEEN angular and angular-mocks

Comment: The same appears true for Jasmine. I needed to include its JS scripts BETWEEN the angular and angular-mocks.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar message and turned out I got my `angular-mocks` file path wrong. I used npm to install `angular` and `angular-mocks`, and I specified their path wrongly in my `Karma.conf.js` like this:

```
files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular-mocks.js',
    'scripts/*.js',
    'tests/*.js'
],
```

I should specify the path of `angular-mocks.js` as this:

```
'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
```

Very simple error, but could be time-consuming to locate if you just started with AngularJS unit testing and didn't know where to look.